# Fifth Cross Validated Journal Club

Tags: discussion, journal-club

Time to continue the CVJC series after holidays!

To remind for those who are new to the idea:

- CVJC is a whole day meeting on [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18/ten-fold) where we discuss some paper and its theoretical/practical surroundings.
- As mentioned above the event is whole-day (00:00-23:59UTC), but there is a  meet-up session on which most talking take place.
- The paper must be OpenAccess or a (p)reprint suggested previously on a meta thread like this one and selected in voting.
- We will try to invite the author(s).

So, please suggest papers (each in one answer)! The deadline for suggestions is traditionally a week ahead, so 23:59UTC 2.11.2011.

EDIT: The JC will certainly take place at **18.11.2011**, with meet-up session at **18:00UTC**. You can register **[here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/18/ten-fold?tab=schedule)** to get an e-mail reminder. One of the authors, Gregory Matthews, will join the discussion.

EDIT2: Here is [the transcript](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18/conversation/cross-validated-journal-club-5).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This article was just posted on the Statistics Surveys website:  [Data confidentiality: A review of methods for statistical disclosure limitation and methods for assessing privacy](http://www.i-journals.org/ss/viewarticle.php?id=74&layout=abstract).

This topic is becoming increasingly relevant and important.

Answer (score 3):

[A guide to modern statistical analysis of immunological data](http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2172/8/27)
Propose some questions to discuss:

- Typical types of distributions in biomedical (immunology, etc.) sciences
- Substantiation for transforming raw data with a given frequency distribution to those with a normal one

and some specific problems:

- Percentages in [immunogram](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2851216/) after angular (arc sin, [$Freeman$ — $Tukey's$](http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&handle=euclid.aoms/1177729756)) transformation [retain assymmetry](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12067/is-freeman-tukeys-transformation-appropriate-and-the-most-powerful-for-perce). Only $Box$ — $Cox$ transformation sometimes helps well but power transformations for frequences (= percentages = proportions) is arbitrariness...
- Difficult asymetric, probably polymodal distributions (for example for cytokines) in some cases and almost bell-shaped ones in the others...